# Assign Column name to values extracted after using jq

Tags: json, shell, header, jq

I'm trying to extract values from JSON data using jq in shell once I get the value i would like to give column name to it.

```
... | jq '.[].name'
```

output should be

```
name
"tom"
"harry"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "," operator, e.g.:

```
jq '"name", .[].name'
```

This will, however, result in `"name"`.

If you really want `name` to be unquoted but the names to be quoted, then consider:

```
jq -r '"name", (.[].name | "\"\(.)\"")'
```

## More than one field

You can use the same strategy with more than one column.  In the following, I'll assume you want TSV output (i.e. with fields separated by tabs):

```
jq -r '["name", "id"], (.[] | [.name, .id]) | @tsv'
```

Comment: yes it need to look like table, but its giving as below 














 Name      Id       pool

"Name of xxxxxxx at somewhere    652     800"
"zzzzzzzzzz         652     800"
"files      3869    4985"